# Virtual machines deployment using count to different availability zones

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to deploy 6 identical virtual machines (except for their names etc.), and spread them across multiple availability zones.

So for example VM1 = Zone 1, VM2 = Zone 2, VM3 = Zone 3, VM4 = Zone 1 and so on.

The terraform code for VM creation I am using is as follows
**MAIN.TF**

```
###################################
# VIRTUAL MACHINE ZONE 1 CREATION #
###################################
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "avd_vm" {
    count = 2
    name = "${var.avd_vm.name}${count.index + 1}"
    resource_group_name = var.rg.name
    location = var.rg.location
    vm_size = var.avd_vm.size
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.avd_nic.*.id[count.index]}"]
    license_type = var.avd_vm.license_type
    delete_os_disk_on_termination = true
    zones = ["1"]
    
    storage_image_reference {
      id = var.avd_vm.image_id
    }

    storage_os_disk {
      name = "${lower(var.avd_vm.os_disk_name)}-${count.index +1}"
      caching = var.avd_vm.caching
      create_option = "FromImage"
      managed_disk_type = var.avd_vm.managed_disk_type
    }

    os_profile {
      computer_name = "${var.avd_vm.name}${count.index + 1}"
      admin_username = var.local_username.username
      admin_password = var.local_password.password
    }

    os_profile_windows_config {
      provision_vm_agent = true
      timezone = var.avd_vm.timezone
    }

    depends_on = [
      azurerm_network_interface.avd_nic
    ]
}
```

I can get it to deploy to a single zone, but not sure how to loop it and deploy to multiple zones.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: Ok, but here you have only `count = 2`. Are you sure there are three zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count.index` and with a bit of math we can loop over the 3 zones you need.

Code will look something like this:

```txt
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "avd_vm" {
    count = 6
    name = "${var.avd_vm.name}${count.index + 1}"
    resource_group_name = var.rg.name
    location = var.rg.location
    ...
    license_type = var.avd_vm.license_type
    delete_os_disk_on_termination = true
    zones = [ count.index % 3 + 1 ]
    ...
}
```